# Weblogic ApplicationLifecycleListener not firing

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a bean that contains a ApplicationLifecycleListener.Like so :

```
package vanzylvi.test;

import weblogic.application.ApplicationLifecycleEvent;

import weblogic.application.ApplicationLifecycleListener;

public class TestApplicationListener  extends ApplicationLifecycleListener {

     public void preStart(ApplicationLifecycleEvent evt) {
         System.out.println("preStart GO GO GO");
     }
}
```

and in my **weblogic-application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
<listener>
     <listener-class>vanzylvi.test.TestApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</weblogic-application>
```

I can never get the preStart bit to fire,any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException since I faced the same issue in the past. In order to fix it, compile the TestApplicationListener class and place it under your EarContent/APP-INF/classes. Your EarContent/APP-INF/classes should contain vanzylvi/test/TestApplicationListener.class.

Your weblogic-application.xml and the TestApplicationListener are correct.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi,I found my issue and to be fair you actually answered it right.I had the weblogic-application.xml in my bean and not in the ear.So you're right it couldn't find my listener class.You win the bounty.Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit later to provide you an answer but [a listener URI](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/lifecycle.htm#i1049839), unless in WebLogic 12, can also be set to avoid adding class files to plain ear file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
<listener>
   <listener-class>vanzylvi.test.TestApplicationListener</listener-class>
   <listener-uri>startup.jar</listener-uri>
</listener>
</weblogic-application>
```